# How to pass variable as associative array field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Let's assume I have an Angular project, where I want to animate a clicked element (having `position: relative`) with jQuery and pass the direction of the animation with a parameter variable like below;

```
onClickFoo(event :MouseEvent, dir :string) :void {
   let targetId :string = (event.currentTarget as Element).id;
   $("#" + targetId).animate({
      dir: "20px"
   });
}
```

The code above gives a `dir=20` attribute to the target HTML element which is not the desired behavior. I think the compiler does not interpret `dir` as a variable, it is rather just perceiving a 'dir' string there.

I am unsure whether the above is the result of combining jQuery and TypeScript, but I have to use variables to determine the animation direction, what am I doing wrong here?

How to make the compiler using `dir` as a variable, rather than just text?

Comment: Enclose it in square brackets like this: `[dir]: "20px"`.

Comment: Oopsie, I've missed 'em brackets. Please post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) to get the behavior you want during object initialization.

```
$("#" + targetId).animate({
  [dir]: "20px"
});
```

It can also be done post-creation, something like this:

```
onClickFoo(event :MouseEvent, dir :string) :void {
   let targetId :string = (event.currentTarget as Element).id;
   const animationProps = {};
   animationProps[dir] = "20px";
   $("#" + targetId).animate(animationProps);
}
```